# Passing string parameters for all internal queries as varchar and not nvarchar using pyodbc in Airflow

Tags: sql-server, airflow, pyodbc

Background: We have Airflow 2.4.3 and the metadata database is SQL Server. Basically [this one](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.3/configurations-ref.html#database) , our case uses sql server .

So, the connection for the internal db is through this connection string

```
[database]

sql_alchemy_conn = mssql+pyodbc://{{ database.user }}:{{ airflow_db_password }}@{{ database.server }}:{{ database.port }}/{{ database.name }}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server
load_default_connections = False
```

Now, the problem is : all of the internal update queries (e.g. when a task is done) sends parameters as `nvarchar`.

In JDBC we can do something like this : [setSendStringParametersAsUnicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/setsendstringparametersasunicode-method-sqlserverdatasource?view=sql-server-ver16).

How does one go about doing the same for pyodbc , connecting to sql sever? Is it possible? I could not find the same method for ODBC.

Problem is these metadata tables have the column data type as varchar, with unique indexes on them and since these internal airflow update queries pass on string parameters as nvarchar, it results in table scans and often deadlocks.

Example of an internal update query

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=2603
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(18),@P2 nvarchar(40),@P3 nvarchar(72),@P4 nvarchar(60),@P5 int',N'UPDATE task_instance SET state=@P1 WHERE task_instance.dag_id = @P2 AND task_instance.run_id = @P3 AND task_instance.task_id = @P4 AND task_instance.map_index = @P5',N'scheduled',N'lead_value_score_1_1',N'scheduled__2022-12-10T09:12:00+00:00',N'predict_funding_scores_instant',-1
```

Notice that all the columns in the where clause are passed on as nvarchar, whereas the table has them as varchar.

Any questions and I can try to answer them.

These update queries are airflow internal and thus we don't control them and thus trying to see if these can be set on the connection level.

Comment: I can't answer your question since I'm not versant in Airflow but the queries will be sargable with Windows collation instead of legacy SQL collation (e.g. `Latin1_General_CI_AS` instead of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`). Changing collation is not trivial but could be an option if you're creating a new database.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Thanks for responding. Can you explain a bit about how changing the collation of the database would make queries sargable?

Comment: [Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support) determines string sorting and comparison rules. Unicode and non-Unicode rules are compatible with Windows collations, allowing sargability when comparing an indexed Windows collation varchar column with a nvarchar parameter. However, comparison rules of Unicode and non-Unicode differ with SQL collations so comparing an indexed SQL collation varchar column with a nvarchar parameter is not a sargable expression, resulting in scans.

Comment: Note that one can change the database collation after creation but that does not change the collation of already created columns. Furthermore, mixing different collations has some gotchas so it's best to use the same collation throughout. If yours is an existing database, it would be best to fix the parameters.

Comment: @SaugatMukherjee Did you find a solution for this? I face this issue with py3.10, SQLAlchemy, pyodbc and MSSQL 2019 on VARCHAR fields as well. All params are cast as NVARCHAR and are leading to delayed query results.